# Drag & Drop like this swf with jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

This is the swf i need to clone to html5 and jquery http://www.gdlab.it/mappa/

Can i keep the features found in the SWF?

Labels can always vary in number and text, put a label on another switch places, and in the end (only when all labels are insrted) checking to see if the answers are correct, if not leave correct answer in the right position and resetting wrong answers to the top.

Tnx in advance

**EDIT**

> html

```
    <h1>This is a jQuery UI draggable TEST!</h1>
    <h2>Sposta questi oggetti nell'ordine esatto</h2>
    <p class="labels">
        <span class="dragme">ipsum</span> <span class="dragme">sit</span> <span class="dragme">dolor</span> <span class="dragme">amet</span> <span class="dragme">lorem</span>
    </p>
    <h2>Posti destinazione</h2>
    <p class="labels">
        <span class="dropme"></span>
    </p>
```

> jquery

```
        $(function() {
            $(".dragme").draggable({
                revert: true,
                revertDuration: 600
            });

            $(".dropme").droppable({
                accept: ".dragme",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').html(ui.draggable);
                }
            });
        });
```

I can't fit draggable perfectly to same dimension span.dropme and i don't know how to change dropped label if i put another label on it (switch places) and return to default top position like example 
:/

Comment: _Can i keep the features found in the SWF?_ Yes.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

You will have to make all the label as `dragable` and all the empty spaces (possibly divs with fixed width) as `dropable`.

see
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
and
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/